# Watir with Ruby: undefined local variable or method `doc' for main:Object

Tags: ruby, web-scraping, screen-scraping, watir, watir-webdriver

I was following [this tutorial](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=2&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwimlbK75YXLAhVIFj4KHQNGDkAQFggjMAE&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.layeredthoughts.com%2Fautomation%2Fhow-to-write-your-first-ruby-web-bot-in-watir-scraping-weather-com&usg=AFQjCNFME-reql2zO1Mx5F8nF6OzX31k-Q&bvm=bv.114733917,d.cWw) for screen scraping with Ruby and Watir.

I tried to write a simple script to return text from Wikipedia:

```
require "selenium-webdriver"
browser = Selenium::WebDriver.for :chrome
browser.get "https://wikipedia.org"
require "nokogiri"
puts doc.xpath(".//*[@id='langsearch-input']/p").inner_text
```

But when I run the script, I get this error in my terminal:

```
$ ruby app/views/layouts/scraper.rb
app/views/layouts/scraper.rb:7:in `<main>': undefined local variable or method `doc' for main:Object (NameError)
```

I have nokogiri 1.6.7.2, watir-webdriver 0.9.1, and watir 4.0.2 installed.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing a line to that converts the browser HTML into a Nokogiri document. In other words, you have not defined what `doc` is.

```
require "selenium-webdriver"
browser = Selenium::WebDriver.for :chrome
browser.get "https://wikipedia.org"
require "nokogiri"
doc = Nokogiri::HTML.parse(browser.page_source)
puts doc.xpath(".//*[@id='langsearch-input']/p").inner_text
#=> ""
```

Note that while this will address the exception, the `inner_text` will return an empty string - ie `""`. The element with id "langsearch-input" is an input field, which dos not have a child `p` element or a text node.

Also note that you are not actually using Watir at all. To use Watir, it would look like:

```
require 'watir-webdriver'
browser = Watir::Browser.new :chrome
browser.goto "https://wikipedia.org"
require 'nokogiri'
doc = Nokogiri::HTML.parse(browser.html)
puts doc.xpath(".//*[@id='langsearch-input']/p").inner_text
#=> ""
```

However, unless you are doing a lot of parsing of a single large HTML chunk, using Watir without Nokogiri might be easier:

```
require 'watir-webdriver'
browser = Watir::Browser.new :chrome
browser.goto "https://wikipedia.org"
puts browser.text_field(id: 'langsearch-input').value
```